# Merge columns based on rows

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to combine columns from different google sheets based on (ID) strings in a single column on both sheets.  This would normally be handled easily by Vlookup but the amount of data I have makes this function grind to a halt even with a relatively small amount of data.

I was hoping that the QUERY function would be able to manage the task but
I am having some difficulty with the syntax for my QUERY and it is returning an unusual result that I can't seem to crack.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A,(QUERY(ParsedResponses!B2:Q,"select D,E where D matches '"&B2:B&"'")),IFERROR(1/0)))
```

The above formula seems to match the first set of strings fine then repeats that for the length of the column but NOT matching the strings row by row as I would like it to!!

An example of my sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AP5kD5K0Rz9_p5WOphyTVUidOVVwTzXZW9XgCU7lvHw/edit?usp=sharing). The formula is in C2 of Sheet1.  The actual dataset is much larger (100 columns by >20,000 rows) but this sample should demonstrate my problem.

I haven't had much experience writing custom functions but would this be a good solution for me rather than the above approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you tried VLOOKUP in ARRAYFORMULA, but maybe give this a try in E2

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B), IFERROR(vlookup(B2:B, ParsedResponses!D2:E, 2, 0)),))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that was exactly the formula that I was using, however it takes over 5 mins to process 10 rows of data (with around 100 columns).  I was hoping to find a more efficient workaround that can be run in a reasonable time.  I'm unsure why vlookup struggles so much with merging this data but it would be ideal if it worked within a few seconds.